# `PROMPT` environment variable cleared after running any command

Tags: shell, configuration, config, zsh

I recently ran into this issue with `zsh`, although I have no idea what caused it. My `PROMPT` environment variable gets cleared after I run any command.

Running `prompt X` where X is any valid theme fixes the issue, but that's a pain.

The relevant lines in my `~/.zshrc` are:

```
autoload -Uz promptinit
promptinit
prompt powerline
```

Comment: After `autoload -Uz promptinit` there should be a line with the command `promptinit`, before running `prompt powerline`. Did you just forget posting it, or is it actually missing?

Comment: forgot to post it.